# Compiling for older version of .net in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is it possible to compile using an older version of .net framework while using VS2010? (which requires .net 4 to run if I'm not mistaken).
If so -how is it done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the target framework in the project properties (in the top tab, IIRC). You won't be able to target .NET 1.1 or 1.0, but you should be able to target 2.0/3.0/3.5.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the target framework to .NET 2.0 or above though your project properties.

The location differs between `c#` and `vb`.

In c# go to your project properties, in the `application` tab you can change the target framework to 2.0+ in the drop down.

In vb go to your project properties, click the `compile` tab on the left, click the `advanced compile options` button and the `target framework` drop down box can be found there.